# How to bin data with specific conditions in r

Tags: r, cut, binning

I have a data set that requires me to categorise data to consider changes over time. I want to create a new column that codes a data range. For example, I would want to add a column to the following data set called 'category' where category is 1 when V1 is between 10-13; 2 when V1 is between 14-16; and 3 when V1 is between 17-20.

```
Data<-data.frame(
X = factor(c("SU", "Staff")),
V1 = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20))
```

I previously used the following code to create 5 equal bins, but I now want to specify the range as above:

```
binning <- Data %>% mutate(Category=ntile(Data$'V1', 5))
```

Any help would be appreciated and I am new to r so simple language would be welcomed.

Many thanks,
Laura

Comment: `cut(Data$V1, c(10, 13, 16, 20), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you explain it please. I'm unclear what you mean by include.lowest = true.

Comment: That is used to include the `10` in the interval. Check out `help('cut')`